# Converting duplicate object value to array Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I've spent a couple hours to find a way to handling this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "value": "foo01",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo02",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo03",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo04",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar4"
  }
]
```

My Expected JSON is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name":"bar",
    "value":[
      {
        "value": "foo01",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["Tidak ada"],
        "name": "bar",
      },
      {
        "value": "foo02",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["Tidak ada"],
        "name": "bar",
      },
      {
        "value": "foo03",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["Tidak ada"],
        "name": "bar",
      },
      {
        "value": "foo04",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["Tidak ada"],
        "name": "bar",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bar2",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "val1",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["foo03"],
        "name": "bar2",
      },
      {
        "value": "val2",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["foo01"],
        "name": "bar2",
      },
      {
        "value": "val3",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["foo02", "foo04"],
        "name": "bar2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bar3",
    "value":[
      {
        "value": "val1",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["foo01"],
        "name": "bar3",
      },
      {
        "value": "val2",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["foo03", "foo04"],
        "name": "bar3",
      },
      {
        "value": "val3",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["foo02"],
        "name": "bar3",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bar4",
    "value": [
      {
        "value": "val1",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["foo01", "foo02", "foo04"],
        "name": "bar4",
      },
      {
        "value": "val2",
        "Diagnosis_Code": ["foo03"],
        "name": "bar4",
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to put duplicate `name` value into `Object` and if the `Diagnosis_Code` of json is same as another value, put it into an array

The code I've use for now is just to using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to handle the `name`, but I don't know how to handle the `Diagnosis_Code` property:

```js
var orgArray = [{"value":"foo01","Diagnosis_Code":"Tidak ada","name":"bar"},{"value":"foo02","Diagnosis_Code":"Tidak ada","name":"bar"},{"value":"foo03","Diagnosis_Code":"Tidak ada","name":"bar"},{"value":"foo04","Diagnosis_Code":"Tidak ada","name":"bar"},{"value":"val1","Diagnosis_Code":"foo03","name":"bar2"},{"value":"val2","Diagnosis_Code":"foo01","name":"bar2"},{"value":"val3","Diagnosis_Code":"foo02","name":"bar2"},{"value":"val3","Diagnosis_Code":"foo04","name":"bar2"},{"value":"val1","Diagnosis_Code":"foo01","name":"bar3"},{"value":"val2","Diagnosis_Code":"foo03","name":"bar3"},{"value":"val2","Diagnosis_Code":"foo04","name":"bar3"},{"value":"val3","Diagnosis_Code":"foo02","name":"bar3"},{"value":"val1","Diagnosis_Code":"foo01","name":"bar4"},{"value":"val1","Diagnosis_Code":"foo02","name":"bar4"},{"value":"val1","Diagnosis_Code":"foo04","name":"bar4"},{"value":"val2","Diagnosis_Code":"foo03","name":"bar4"}];

var newArray = orgArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  var findIfNameExist = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.name === curr.name;
  })
  if (findIfNameExist === -1) {
    let obj = {
      'name': curr.name,
      "value": [curr]
    }
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    acc[findIfNameExist].value.push(curr)
  }
  return acc;

}, []);
console.log(newArray)
```

Is there a way of handling transforming the duplicate `Diagnosis_Code`s into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.reduce` to convert the array into an object, as you're doing, but then you need to `.find` twice to see if the matching `name` and then if the matching `value` object exists. `find` (or `.findIndex`) just once won't be enough.

```js
const input = [
  {
    "value": "foo01",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo02",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo03",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo04",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar4"
  }
];

const output = input.reduce((accum, item) => {
  const { name } = item;
  let foundNameObj = accum.find(({ name: findName }) => findName === name);
  if (!foundNameObj) {
    foundNameObj = { name, value: [] };
    accum.push(foundNameObj);
  }
  const foundValObj = foundNameObj.value.find(({ value }) => value === item.value);
  if (!foundValObj) {
    // value hasn't appeared before, we can just push the item:
    foundNameObj.value.push({...item, Diagnosis_Code: [item.Diagnosis_Code] });
    return accum;
  }
  foundValObj.Diagnosis_Code.push(item.Diagnosis_Code);
  return accum;
}, [])
console.log(output);
```

Don't mix `var` and `let`/`const` - if you're using ES6, which you should be, always use `const`, except when you need to reassign, in which case use `let`. (`var` is hoisted and has function scope rather than block scope, which is unintuitive and can lead to unexpected bugs)

Comment: but how do you handle `Diagnosis_Code` to be an array even there's just have 1 value?

Comment: Oh, I thought they stayed as individual strings when there was only one item because I was scrolled to the bottom. Under what conditions do they turn into arrays rather than strings when there's just one value?

Comment: though there's no conditions about `Diagnosis_Code`, it should be an array if there's only have one or more value

Comment: Please fix your `My Expected JSON` then, because it has strings.

Comment: sorry about it, I'm not realized it's not completed edit, but your code should work, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example!

First, I use reduce to reduce your object, then, I use map to remap it to get the expected format ;)

It may not be the best-performance way to do this, but I find it is the more maintainable and readable way though.

I hope this is clear and will help you :D

```js
const input = [
  {
    "value": "foo01",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo02",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo03",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "foo04",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "Tidak ada",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val3",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo01",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo02",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val1",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo04",
    "name": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "value": "val2",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "foo03",
    "name": "bar4"
  }
];

// Condensed/reduced object.
let output = input.reduce((accum, item) => {
  if(!accum[item.name]) {
    accum[item.name] = {};
  }
  if(!accum[item.name][item.value]) {
    accum[item.name][item.value] = [];
  }
  accum[item.name][item.value].push(item.Diagnosis_Code);
  accum[item.name][item.value].original = item;
  return accum;
}, {});

// Object remapped to fit your expected format.
output = Object.keys(output).map((itemName) => {
  return {
    'name': itemName,
    'value': Object.keys(output[itemName]).map((valueName) => {
    const patchedOriginalItem = output[itemName][valueName].original;
    patchedOriginalItem['Diagnosis_Code'] = output[itemName][valueName];
      return patchedOriginalItem;
    })
  };
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: i can't do that, because the `value[index].value` will be dynamically

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the problem, can you be more precise? I mean, what's going to be dynamic? You have a static object, you want to transform it in another format.

Comment: your return inside `value` arrays is harcoded, with `name, value, and Diagnosis_Code` keys, but how can i handle those array if I have more than 3 object inside arrays, so I need to declared the others too, right?

Comment: Hmm ok, I get it, you want the exact original object! I'm going to edit :)

Comment: Here it is :) I'm just patching the `Diagnosis_Code` attribute to get the condensed array version ;)